# From XHTML to HTML5 of not using self-closing tag, now JSX will use it again?

Tags: reactjs, jsx

From https://titobouzout.github.io/react/tips/self-closing-tag.html, it says:

> In JSX, `<MyComponent />` alone is valid while `<MyComponent>` isn't. All
>   tags must be closed, either with the self-closing format or with a
>   corresponding closing tag (`</MyComponent>`).
>
> Note:
>   Every React component can be self-closing: `<div />`. `<div></div>`
>   is also an equivalent.

So it seems from the XHTML going forward to HTML5, that we don't use self-closing tag, now when we move to JSX, we will use it again?

I am more concerned about `<input />` and `<img ... />` because it seems we cannot write `<input>` and `<img ...>` but have to write `<input />` and `<img ... />`?